# Why $cursor return 45 limits when I limit the number of returned result to 40

Tags: php, json, mongodb

```
    $startplushowmany=$startfrom+$howmany; //$startplush is 40
    $cursor=$cursor->limit($startplushowmany);  

    $numberReturned=$cursor->count();   //$numberReturned is 45
```

I can't show you the content of the $cursor because $cursor do not implement _toString. Please let me know how to do so.

Now the query in the $cursor is defined by this command:
    $cursor = $collection->find($rangeQuery, $field);

where $rangeQuery is

```
(string:592) Array
(
    [LongitudeLatitude] => Array
        (
            [$within] => Array
                (
                    [$center] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 106.772835
                                    [1] => -6.186753
                                )

                            [1] => 0.044983732050783
                        )

                )

        )

    [indexContents] => bas
    [Prominent] => Array
        (
            [$gte] => 15
        )

)
```

and

$field is

```
(string:39) Array
(
    [LongitudeLatitude] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a boolean flag to have count taking limit in consideration, else it gives the actual
count

`$numberReturned=$cursor->count(true);`

Quoting example from [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.count.php) :

```
<?php

$collection->insert(array('x'=>1));
$collection->insert(array('x'=>2));
$collection->insert(array('x'=>3));

$cursor = $collection->find();

var_dump($cursor->count());
var_dump($cursor->count(true));

$cursor->limit(2);

var_dump($cursor->count());
var_dump($cursor->count(true));

?>
```

Will output :

```
int(3)
int(3)
int(3)
int(2)
```